# Arch:pip: ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'

Tags: arch-linux, python, pip

Some of my python packages installed with pip had conflicts with another package I tried installing using pacman. So I decided to uninstall all the packages installed with pip. I made a requirements.txt file with all the packages and started uninstalling them. It worked fine for a while but eventually gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==10.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 479, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2703, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2321, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2327, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'
```

I got a similar error everytime I tried running pip after that.

Comment: You probably got mismatched libraries built for different versions of python (as it may happen these days of switch from 3.6 to 3.7). You should just have needed to check [python-requests](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/python-requests/) dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you used `sudo pip` and ended up mixing-and-matching `pacman` packages and `pip` packages. Do not do this. If you need to use `pip` with a distribution installation of Python, use the `--user` flag, or better yet, a virtualenv.

In order to fix this, you need to uninstall everything you installed with pip, using e.g. the `lostfiles` package from the official repositories which will find files that pacman does not know about. Delete all this clutter, then use pacman to reinstall python-pip.

You may also need to check for packages with broken dependencies using `pacman -Dk`, or corrupted packages which have files you've deleted or replaced using pip which should belong to pacman, using `pacman -Qkk`.

Comment: The issue was solve here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542994/archlinuxpip-importerror-cannot-import-name-requests

Comment: It is not solved by installing `python-cachecontrol`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the issue but I simply fixed it by

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py; python get-pip.py
```